# How do I add a dependency to my application?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, dependencies

I'm currently working on an application called SatStressGUI, a GUI application written in Python, which was passed down to me from previous interns who have worked on it. It relies on dependencies such as wxPython (which, as most of you probably know, must be installed on the user's own computer before the application the user is trying to run runs properly if the application calls on the the wxPython library). In the gitHub, under contents->resources->lib->python2.5->sitepackages, you'll see all the libraries which the application is dependent on (wxPython is under the name wx, for example) copied and pasted. If I am correct, the existence of these libraries in sitepackages makes it so that the user does not have to manually install libraries such as wxPython themselves: the user can simply run the GUI application by downloading the whole package under "clone or download" in the main page and run the satstressgui executable file located in contents->MacOS. I believe there is a file somewhere, perhaps **boot**.py (located in contents->resources) that says, "hey, before the user runs this executable file, download the libraries under contents->resources->lib->python2.5->sitepackages."

All that being said, I want to add a new dependency to the program. I am trying to use FFMPEG, which is an external program that allows you to take a sequence of images and convert it to a video. In satstressgui.py, which is the main source code file for this application (located in contents->resources) I use the subprocess python module to call on the external program FFMPEG. Here is the code snippet:

```
#FFMPEG is an external program that converts a sequence of images to a video. 
subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-framerate', \
                         framerate, '-f', 'image2','-pattern_type', \
                         'glob', '-i', self.directory + '/orbit_*.png', \
                         '-r', '10', '-s', '620x380', self.directory + 
                         ".avi"])
```

At the moment, this works on my own computer because I have FFMPEG installed (in case it matters, I installed it using homebrew). How do I make it so that FFMPEG becomes a dependency in my program just like wxPython (i.e., I make it so that FFMPEG is "installed" on my user's computer before they run the application)? I've looked on FFMPEG's website and it looks as if there is a gitHub for it, but other than that I'm quite lost.

NOTE: I've also tried to use imageio (another Python library) to convert a sequence of images to a video in my application, but I've failed. I tried to copy and paste the files from imageio's gitHub to contents->resources->lib->python2.5->sitepackages, but whenever I try to "import imageio" it fails. This might be because I am adding the dependency wrong or because imageio only works on Python 2.6 and above and my program is written in Python 2.5. If someone could give me an answer to any of these questions and help me import a module such as imageio or add an external program such as FFMPEG as a dependency in my application, that'd be very much appreciated! I can't link imageio's main website because of some restrictions by Stack Overflow, but you should be able to find it by simply searching it up on google (the main website has a photo of an astronaut in it's top banner). I would more prefer a solution using FFMPEG, however, seeing as I've already implemented it in my code.

Thank you so much in advance for your help! I'm quite new to computer science and programming so I apologize if a lot of the clarifications or questions I'm asking are rudimentary.

Here is the link to the gitHub of my application: https://github.com/nhudoan/SatStressGUI

Here is the link to FFMPEG's main website: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#repositories

Comment: Please just put your [minimum, complete, verifiable example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here so your specific problem can be addressed.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a specific code bit so that you guys don't have to look through the file yourselves.

Comment: This is probably not the correct forum. Sounds like a github site configuration request.

Comment: Further to @Ron, besides [mcve] - you may also want to read [help/on-topic] and [ask], and re-word your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I realize this question is a lot more indepth than most. But the reason I included so much detail was because I feel I need really specialized help to fix my problem. My question isn't something I can sum up in a sentence or two, I hope you understand. I appreciate anyone who is willing to look at this and offer their constructive guidance. Thanks!